# Wildcard Search character in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to make a wildcard search character (ex. Binary%) so when they click search it finds all the files with the word Binary in the filename and loads them into a list box. My current code is below.

```
Private Sub _test_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles _test.TextChanged
    For x As Integer = 0 To _listbox.Items.Count - 1
        If _listbox.Items(x).ToString = _test.Text$ Then
            _listbox.SelectedIndex = x
            Return
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is welcome!

Thank you!
-Kyvex

Comment: Are you looking for `If _listbox.Items(x).ToString.StartsWith(_test.Text$) Then`?

Comment: The reason why I added the excel tag @Comintern is because the files are excel sheets. And I am trying to make it to where if they put it in a number for instance like 1800213% it will go through all the files and find every filename that has 1800213 at the beginning and load it into a listbox but in order for the wildcard search to work you have to have the % symbol

Comment: [`Like` Operator (Visual Basic) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Comment: @VisualVincent I have looked at the Like Operator before I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You just substitute the equality operator (`=`) for it, as the input string that you search for can contain a pattern (like you said). It works exactly the same way as the equality operator apart from that it matches a pattern instead of an exact string. Check the docs for usage examples.

Comment: @Kyvex If the search character you want to use is not the same as the one that the Like operator uses, you can [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) it in the string.

Comment: @VisualVincent Im having such a hard time with this haha! I've tried and tried this like operator and nothing.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking doesn't really match your code.

1. ... "**when they click search** it finds all the files" ...

   But you have a **TextChanged** event handler of a **TextBox** (not a Button)
2. ..."with the word Binary in the filename and **loads them into a list box**"

   But you select *only the first* item which matches the filter of items already in a ListBox

To get your code to do what it seems to want to do, simply use the `Like` operator and add the wildcard character (`*`) after the TextBox.Text

```
For x As Integer = 0 To _listBox.Items.Count - 1
    If _listBox.Items(x).ToString Like _test.Text & "*" Then
        _listBox.SelectedIndex = x
        Return
    End If
Next
```

Now you can select the first item in the listbox which matches the filter

If you have a multi-select ListBox, you can use this

```
If _test.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
_listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
For x As Integer = 0 To _listBox.Items.Count - 1
    _listBox.SetSelected(x, _listBox.Items(x).ToString Like _test.Text & "*")
Next
```

(the filter logic is the same as the first example)

And you can make it case-insensitive

```
_listBox.SetSelected(x, _listBox.Items(x).ToString().ToUpper() Like _test.Text.ToUpper() & "*")
```